# What's the difference between gzip and compress?

Tags: compression, gzip

What is the difference between gzip and compress? What are the advantages of using compress function. I could see a size difference in the compressed file, but apart from this what are the main adavantages?

Comment: `compress` is 80s technology, `gzip` 90s, `bzip2` 00s, `xz` 10s.

Answer (score 6):

Compress is significantly older (1983) and based on the LZW compression algorithm.

Gzip was written in the early 90's and is based on the DEFLATE algorithm.

In general Compress will run faster and use less memory, but gzip will generally reach significantly higher levels of compression.

There were also patent issues with LZW that Unisys started enforcing in the early 90's (this was mostly targeted toward the GIF format that also used LZW compression). The gzip developers intended to develop general purpose compression software that was unencumbered by patents.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR: `gzip` is better than `compress`.** Other tools might be faster/better still, e.g. `pigz` is faster and gzip-compatible.

I did some tests to compare the compression level, compression time and decompression time of `gzip`, `compress` and`xz` (just to have a bit more context, this is not a comprehensive compression tool comparison):

```
File size
|    Percentage of original size
|    |    Time to compress
|    |    |    Time to decompress
|    |    |    |    Method
|    |    |    |    |        Filename
425M 100% -    -    -        Germany_hessen_europe_2.obf
348M  82% 16.8 3.24 compress test.Z
260M  61% 11.8 4.18 gzip -1  test.1.gz
246M  58% n/a  3.88 gzip -9  test.9.gz
226M  53% 69.6 15.6 xz -1    test.1.xz
```

The file is a map of a German state [downloaded from OsmAnd](https://osmand.net/list.php), which compresses pretty well (by 50% with a bit of effort).

In short:

- `compress` is slower than `gzip -1` when compressing,
- it compresses only half as well, but
- it is 29% faster when decompressing.

---

Test method: I used an idle SSD and I/O was not the bottleneck. I used `time cat file | compression > out` for compression and `time cat file | decompression > /dev/null` for decompression times. Tests for `gzip -1` and `compress` were run twice (both compress and decompress) and gave very similar results, of which I took the average. The `gzip -9` compression time I simply forgot to measure, but since `-1` already compresses a lot better than `compress` I don't think it would add much to go back and do it.

Comment: What about `pigz` (should be much faster than `gzip`) and why is the compress time noch available for `-9`?

Comment: @mgutt Good suggestion, and reading this back now I also feel like bzip2 is missing and zstd... but then seeing the question, it's really about the difference between gzip and compress, and I took one other (xz) as a comparison I think. So this is not supposed to be a comprehensive comparison but rather makes clear that the traditional `compress` is pretty dated. It's only faster when decompressing, and `pigz` does not improve that iirc/afaik because it only multithreads the compression.

Comment: I didn't tested it by myself, but he says `pigz` gives a "significant improvement" on decompressing: https://serverfault.com/a/270825/44086

Comment: @mgutt Good point, I edited the summary on top, does that sound like what you meant to add? Also feel free to just submit an edit suggestion :)